# Title + inline image upload (BLOB) portlet for Plone

Tags: plone

Are there any existing add-ons which would provide the functionality

- Upload image from local computer (blob)
- Add some title
- Add some link

This functionality can be achieved via Static Text portlet and separate image uploads, but this causes great headache usability wise. We want inline uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now add-on on its way:

https://github.com/miohtama/imageportlet/

Answer (score 0):

The addon collective.quickupload do the job to let you upload multiple files and images and set title of each one of them.

But I guess I miss understood the question because you already know this addon right ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great opportunity to extend the static text portlet!